# PhoneGap backKey Function

Tags: android, cordova

sorry im still a newbie in Android Development. Im using eclipse with Phonegap 1.4.1, and im having a little bit of trouble regarding the backButton cause the app totally closes when I press it. Ive initially posted a question here. and Ive seen a lot of suggestions. Thanks to the experts. but this is query. 
Could you guys give me an example code on how will I set the backKey to go back to previous activity. a sample code of yours. cause honestly I dont know where to start or what to code. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you take a look a PhoneGap's API. There's something here about the back button event.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_events_events.md.html#backbutton

You can see a full example on how to handle this event. Then you juste have to put whatever you want when the back button is tapped.

Comment: can you give me a sample code? on how things can be done? please? im newbie at programming. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> on how will I set the backKey to go back to previous activity.

Congrats. You're already done :)

Seriously, I think before adding some source you shall understand that Phonegap is running in only one activity presenting your html-code probably in a WebView. (ok, that's a long shot, don't burn me if I'm wrong in this detail!).

However the back Button works as intended cause it takes you back to the previous activity. If you want to use the back button inside your phonegap application take TDeBaileul's advice and implement the eventListener.

When I started a couple of weeks ago these callBack Function gave me head ache so here some snippet:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(){
  //if you have some sites visitied go back to a previous site
  //else exit app
}, false);
```

So that's the if-else fork you've to implement. But I'm not spoiling all the fun for you: There's still the need to determine if you have some sites visited beforehand and how to navigate directly back to them. An array with tag words would be one possibility.

If the array is empty close the app, if not change back to the page defined in the array entry.

Answer (score -1):

```
  document.addEventListener('backbutton', function() 
            { 
                device.exitApp();
                // or do other things
            }, true);
```

Comment: Question: "honestly I dont know where to start or what to code. Thanks a lot." -- Sorry but an uncommented piece of code is actually worse than no answer at all.